# Add annotation in Ibooks

Tags: osx-yosemite, ibooks

How can I add annotations on my book using iBooks?

Any time that I try to create an annotation, iBooks wants to create a new copy, with this message:

The original document can't be changed, so a duplicate with your changes has been created.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).